1920s Florida Craftsman Bungalow - Front Porch Deck
So I need to remove and replace my somewhat small covered front porch on my 1927 Florida Bungalow. I bought in 2019; porch was already showing some signs of rot at a couple board ends, since then its gotten worse and I feel like just replacing it myself. Its currently painted 1x4 T&G pine. Obviously not original but i like the look. I got under it and joists are in great shape. I want to stay with a real wood product but all I can find is untreated pine T&G. Is that what I need to use? If so I'm assuming I need to prime and paint both top and bottom. I thought about cedar but I can seem to find any that's not "v-groove" T&G. Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated.
